# Azure: is there a graph tells what resources needed to deploy something?

Tags: azure-devops

e.g. to create a storage, I need the following:

resource group --> storage account --> container

to deploy a webapp, I need the following:

resource group --> app service plan -->

You got what I mean. It's good for beginners like me.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a graph tells what resources needed to deploy something?

For this issue, I am afraid that there is no such graph to tell what resources are needed to deploy something.

If you are using azure devops pipeline to deploy, the tasks will display the settings that you are required to fill in. For example `Azure Web App Deploy` task:

[image]

If you are creating services in azure portal, then you can find the required resources by searching for documents, and the settings you need to fill in will also be displayed on the creation page. For example [Create a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it will be good if somebody can build such a diagram.

Comment: This is helpful, but not what I asked. I am thinking about designing the set of APIs required to automate the provisioning resources and deploying applications. A put together graph will really helpful so I will try to draw myself from what you suggested.